# Facebook {user-id}/picture returning NULL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have an app which uses PHP to fetch user images from facebook after login. 
using `{userid}/picture`

The conventional method stopped working because it's returning an "Update your browser" message.
I used to use `file_get_contents()` before

I now use `CURL` with a browser user-agent or `file_get_contents` with context.

It seems to be working fine but after a while, Facebook starts returning null. Like it's just a blank page returned.

How should I address this problem?

I know many others facing this problem as well. But I can also see some websites working fine.

Here is the **old code** I use to fetch the image before:

```
$im = file_get_contents($url);
```

Here is the **New code** I use:

```
function get_file($url) {
      $options = array(
                  'http' => array(
                      'method'=>"GET",
                      'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n".
                      "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2\r\n"
                )
              );

      $context  = stream_context_create($options);

      $data = ""

      $data = @file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

      return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you using curl now?

Comment: @luschn there was a typo in the question..sorry
"I now use CURL with a browser user-agent or file_get_contents with context."

Comment: @luschn both curl and this functions gives me the same result

Comment: did you try with some curl debug options? or with the api explorer? (which would be a better idea)

Comment: @luschn I believe the code is working. this is some kind of rate limiting from facebook. any way around that?

Comment: if the code would be working, you would not be on stackoverflow with it :) - and if there would be rate limiting, you would get an error message (again, check with curl options or the api explorer) and you would see it in the app settings too.

Comment: try the api call in the api explorer (of course with selecting your app). that´s the best you can do.

Comment: Do you need to do anything with the image (manipulation, composition, ...) - or are you just showing it to users? If it is the latter, then you should not request them server-side to begin with, but just use `<img src="...">` on the client. If you need to download them server-side, then pass a valid access token along with the request, that should help in Facebook not assuming that you’re up to something shady so quickly.

Comment: @luschn I thought people who are good with facebook api could tell me a better way to fetch profile pictures from facebook.

Comment: @CBroe Unfortunatily I have to do some image manipulations and also add some text

Comment: curl with an access token, that´s the best way imho, for your case